# Android Studio - mark code lines to navigate between them with one click

Tags: android-studio

Consider the mock code below. I have 10-15 web calls and each one has a response.

I would like to mark the line that makes the call with the line that handles its response so that I can easily navigate between them with one click.

For example makeCall_2 is marked with ** so clicking on the ** should take me to the line of onCallReposnse_2

Is this capability available in Android Studio or is there such a tool/plugin that can do something like that?

```
class BlaBla extends Activity{

  * void makeCall_1(){
        ....
    }

 ** void makeCall_2(){
        ....
    }


    @Override
  * public void onCallResponse_1(CallResponseData data){
       ...
    }


    @Override
 ** public void onCallResponse_2(CallResponseData data){
       ...
    }

}
```

Comment: You can usually Ctrl + Click on method calls and it would navigate you to the method body, if that helps.

Comment: I'm not trying to navigate form a usage of a function to its declaration. I want to link two seperate functions so that I can navigate from one to the other